# python imap multiprocessing resulting in slower execution

Tags: python, python-2.7, multiprocessing

I'm doing some preprocessing on bunch of text files, and when i did the imap version for it, the end result is even slower than normal sequential execution.

```
def process_text((document)):
    #doing_some_more_preprocessing_on_text
    # extract named entities
    return named_entities

def input_files(dir, fname):
    # read each document as one big string
    document = open(os.path.join(dir, fname)).read()
    #tokenise here
    yield tokenize(document)

def corpus_preprocessing(top_dir):
    # save to another directory, if not exist, create one.
    if not os.path.exists(top_dir+'_pre'):
        os.makedirs(top_dir+'_pre')

    # real multiprocessing starts here
    for fname in os.listdir(top_dir):
        for named_entities in pool.imap(process_text, input_files(top_dir, fname)):
            with open(os.path.join(top_dir+'_pre', fname),'w') as handle:
                json.dump(named_entities, handle)


    pool.terminate()

# initialize pool
pool = Pool(multiprocessing.cpu_count())

# let's calculate time
now = time.time()

#provide the path to dataset here
top_dir = '/home/dataset/sample'

corpus_preprocessing(top_dir)

# print total time taken
print "Finished in", time.time()-now , "sec"
```

I've also enables, logging:

```
with imap:
[WARNING/MainProcess] doomed
[WARNING/MainProcess] doomed
[WARNING/MainProcess] doomed
[WARNING/MainProcess] doomed
[WARNING/MainProcess] doomed
[WARNING/MainProcess] doomed
Finished in 29.0439419746 sec

with single file at a time execution:
Finished in 18.4209680557 sec
```

Does the "doomed" message means all the process dies quickly, leaving just one process to finish everything? Any suggestion what's wrong am i doing with multiprocessing ?

Comment: You do not provide enough information. There are functions you use, but it is not clear, what they do. Try to create simplified example, the process of simplifying is likely to help you already.

Comment: Move your `json.dump` into `input_files` as you don't really need sequential file creation - it can be done by each process separately.

Comment: Is it better now?, i added some comment with my core function.

Comment: @kroolik, but input_files() is the input to imap, json.dump is once i have my output from process_text.

Comment: @kroolik or may be i just do json.dump once i have output in process_text(), that way every process finishes dumping in their own process.

Comment: i think i figured out, instead of passing single file, i should pass group of files as input : `for fname in os.listdir(top_dir):` to `for group in _files_from_dir_:`

Comment: Yeah, sorry I've mistaken the loop code. What I meant was that you could just move the `json.dump` into the end of `process_text` so that when a process is finished, it'd also flush everything to a file instead of doing it internally.